# Highstock- limit grid lines for y axis

Tags: highcharts

How i can only show grid lines only on the middle of the chart, please see the attached image

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop over all ticks and remove gridLines which are not at first / last and zero point.

```
$.each(chart.yAxis[0].ticks,function(i,line){
        if(!line.isFirst && !line.isLast && line.pos!=0) {
            line.gridLine.destroy();
        }
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/hjpchasj/2/